# "To rain" is to "rainy", as "to ..." is to "sunny"?

Tags: verbs, adjectives

Is there a verb that fits this analogy:

`to rain` is to `rainy`, as `___` is to `sunny`?

I know you can say that it is now raining, but can you say that it is now `___`, meaning it is sunny? Is there a verb for this weather? ... "sunshining"? "sunlighting"? "sunshowing"?

Comment: The sun is shining. Don't need the dummy it if there's an actual agent.

Comment: @RegDwightΒВBẞ8 So, there is no special word? I figured since the it rains from the sky, it could also "sun" from the sky. But if the sun shining is the default condition, then it would make sense that it is treated differently. ^_^

Comment: @iglvzx Also keep in mind that "to sun" is a verb, albeit one less used in colloquial speech. It means just what you say.

Comment: @sidran32- "To sun" is a verb- it means to lie or bask in the sun, as in the lizard is on the rock sunning himself.  It doesn't mean what iglvzx said.

Comment: @Jim It depends. That is its intransitive form. However, just like "the sky rains on the ground as the clouds gather", you could say "the sky suns the ground as the clouds disperse". So, in certain usage, they are analogous.

Comment: @sidran32- No, I don't think you *can* say that.  (Well ok you *could* say that, but everybody would give you strange looks and wonder what country you came from.)

Comment: @Jim I would agree that it would be an odd phrase in colloquial speech, but it appears to me to be grammatically valid. To me, it sounds like something you may read in a literary work.

Comment: @sidran- Sorry, but no.  You will not find "*The sky suns the ground*" in any literary work.  It is not a semantically valid sentence.

Comment: @sidran: I think Jim's right. Grammatically, "The sky suns the ground" may be valid – but so are [MadLibs](http://www.write-better-english.com/Create-a-silly-story.aspx). Without a reputable dictionary listing _sun_ as a verb, meaning _to shine as the sun; to shine sunshine on_, such use would be, at best, as chancy as the weather.

Comment: @J.R. [The OED has “sun” as a transitive verb](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/194051) meaning “to place in or expose to the sun; to subject to the action of the sun’s rays; to warm, dry, etc. in sunshine.” Wordsworth wrote *“Spring parts the clouds with softest airs, / That she may sun thee.”*  I presume the OED counts as a “reputable”  dictionary.

Comment: @tchrist: Actually, most dictionaries list that meaning of _sun_; that was discussed earlier in the conversation. (And yes, I'd consider OED reputable) :^) Even with that definition of sun in the books, though, I'm not sure **rain : rainy :: sun : sunny** works, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks, that's precisely what I was trying to get at. I also wasn't aware of the Wordsworth quote, so the similarity is a pleasant surprise.

Comment: It is good that Wordsworth left some sensible examples of the word "sun" used as a verb because I also sun things, such as: my quilts, pillows, and anything else that needs freshening, naturally:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some days I awake to rain.

Other days I awake to shine.

[Rain or shine](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rain+or+shine), sunny or rainy, I awake.

Comment: Rain or shine, this is the answer. +1

Comment: Is *shine* the right answer?  Here's my thought: A weather forecaster might say "It'll be rainy tomorrow," or, "It will rain tomorrow." That same forecaster may say, "It'll be sunny on Friday," but I'm not sure about "It will shine on Friday." Anyway, it's a vexing question with no obvious answer, and I'm very sorry if anyone has an *Annie-Tommorrow* earworm after reading my comment.

Comment: But I awake to sunshine (if fortunate).

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of an unambiguously clear verb for this situation. Of your three suggestions "sunshining" is the only one which would portray meaning, but it is not a real verb. There are, however, expression which portray an action for this kind of whether, such as "The sun is shining outside" or even perhaps "It is shining brightly," but "It is shining" does not unambiguously relate to weather like "to rain" and "to snow" do.

Answer (score 0):

To look at the first half, "rainy" is an adjective that derives from the verb "to rain". But, "sunny" is an adjective which can derive from the action "to have sun". But, you can also use "sun" as a verb, so the statement `... as to sun is to sunny.` would be valid. However, it may sound awkward if you're not used to using it in that way.

If you want a single-word equivalent for being sunny, you could choose something else, such as:

```
... as to radiate is to radiant.
... as to shine is to shiny.
... as to brighten is to bright.
```